# Founders of the Stack Exchange network

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-history

Who is/are the founder(s) of the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: User no-1

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: User no-4

Comment: I read some stuff about Jeff, I thought he stepped down? Maybe I need to read more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about other people's private business.


Comment: @Rosinante not if the answers are from public sources, as per below :)

Comment: I just want to know the reason of my question getting this much **anonymous downvotes** at least give the reason as comment.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Only those who did it could say. And clearly they haven't said. All I can guess is this is likely searchable info and didn't need a question...

Comment: I didn't downvote but like @James said, you could find this by searching in Google or taking a look in the About page of Stack Exchange main site. James, Jeff did step down but he's still one the people who founded Stack Exchange.

Comment: I simply thought one thing-

`If I have to know about a person a very basic info **should I ask him or someone else**`???

This situation is analogous to what I just did.

Comment: @RajeshPaul fair point but still, one is expected to do some research even here on Meta before posting. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from [Stack Exchange About page](https://stackexchange.com/about):

> **Where did Stack Exchange come from?**
>
> In 2008, **Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky created a site called Stack Overflow** and brought together millions of computer programmers from around the world to help each other with detailed technical questions.

Answer (score 8):

Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.

[Here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-1/) is the very first podcast, and the wikipedia entries for [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) and the [Stack Exchange Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network).